# Is there a bug in the captcha? I entered the wrong message and my answer was still posted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, captcha

I just got the captcha message for an answer I wanted to post. No problem I entered the message, but made a typo which I only saw just after I submitted. Yet my answer was still posted. The captcha said 'dreaming The' and I entered 'draming The'.

I just wanted to let you guys know. I'm not even sure this is the place to post it.

Comment: Computers don't make typos! Test passed.

Comment: *Did you cry when Bambi's mother were shot? -Yes -No (Bots, don't lie)*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since it's [reCaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/learnmore.html). They allow for a certain % of error margin. Since you're helping transcribing OCR books.

> But if a computer can't read such a CAPTCHA, how does the system know the correct answer to the puzzle? Here's how: Each new word that cannot be read correctly by OCR is given to a user in conjunction with another word for which the answer is already known.
>
> The user is then asked to read both words. If they solve the one for which the answer is known, the system assumes their answer is correct for the new one. The system then gives the new image to a number of other people to determine, with higher confidence, whether the original answer was correct.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! Indeed, let's hope other users won't be as sloppy as I was :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically what happened is that since reCAPTCHA gives you two words, one known and one unknown, you must have made the typo in the unknown word, essentially passing the CAPTCHA.

This has happened to me before, and a lot of times, you can know which word is the one that is known: it looks a lot cleaner than the other one. Not that this knowledge has given me any cheating power that could be used for evil.